# Horror movie with a zombie or possessed butcher chopping meat who starts chopping up his own arm

Tags: story-identification, horror, zombie

As a kid, I had this very recurring image from a movie where a butcher, where he was chopping some meat with a cleaver and then continued chopping up his fingers and his own arm.

I can't really remember his face traits but he had idle eyes and some horrified protagonist discovered it, leading to screams and run.

We had only public tv at that time, which may be around 1982, so no specific horror channel. That makes me think it can't be a really obscure film. I guess it was a zombie or demonic possession film because the butcher didn't seem to suffer anything.

Also I can't recall in which circumstances did I see that scene, I guess I was spying or something because my parents were rather conservative in that sense and wouldn't let me watch anything Romero or, even less, remotely demonic.

Comment: Secondly, can you confirm anything that would make this a film about Science fiction and fantasy and not just a horror film

Comment: @Edlothiad Horror films are on topic. You're right that this question could do with more body though.

Comment: Horror films are on-topic if there's something fantastic or science-fictional about them... but the edit indicating that it may have been a zombie or possession movie helps.

Comment: We didn't have any premium channels, I saw it probably before 1983 and I was six by that year. Can't remember anything else. As it must have been on spanish national television I'm pretty sure it's not very Z or obscure, rather mainstream.

Comment: Could the butcher have been part of a dream sequence?